# What do abbreviations in movie scripts stand for?

Tags: terminology, screenplay

What do abbreviations in movie scripts stand for? For example, `EXT.`, `INT.`, `(O.S.)`, `(V.O.)`, ...

Comment: Unless you specify which abbreviations you're looking for, I'm not sure this'll be a straightforward question. since there could be movie specific, writer specific, era specific etc...

Comment: @Vishwa, I don't think your comment is relevant here. Since there are a number of default standard abbreviations in movie scripting used by all script writers

Comment: Relevancy is matter of perspective dude. anyway, if you're looking for default/standard abbreviations, then you should mention it in your question. Even though if there is *default standard abbreviations* like you say, it'll still be a broad area to cover, isn't it? and how can one consider which are the standards? I don't know if there's any official guidelines , if there's then it'll be usable as a foundation to get what you're looking for

Comment: @Vishwa, If a question is a straightforward question or not is a matter of perspective.

Comment: yes.. by all means *if*

Answer (score 40):

These abbreviations represent the type of scene and the area where it's being filmed.

From [this glossary](http://www.screenwriting.info/glossary.php) and [this page](https://freelance101.files.wordpress.com/2008/10/script-abbreviations.pdf) from abbreviations used in movie scripts,

> **EXT.** => Exterior
>
> **INT.** => Interior
>
> **O.S.** => Abbreviation for Off Screen, denoting that the speaker is not resident within the scene.
>
> **V.O.** => Abbreviation for Voice Over, denoting that the speaker is narrating the action onscreen.

You can find more abbreviations on the linked pages.

Comment: Really, the only other common ones I can think of would be FX/SFX (sound effect) and MOS (silent)--oh, and POV (shot from the character's point of view).

Comment: MOS= Man of Steel ;)